# Preserving data while expanding/merging Core Data models

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, data-management

Two separate but related questions regarding the use of Core Data:

1. I add an entity/attribute/relationship to my Core Data model in Xcode.  Is there a way to have it recognize the information in the existing `storedata` file and augment it, instead of simply saying that it is incompatible with the existing model?

   For example, if I have a `cars` entity and I decide to add a `manufacturers` entity with 1:many a relationship between the two, how can I import the existing `cars` entries?
2. Modifying the example in #1: If I have two existing Core Data models, one with `cars` and one with `manufacturers`, is there a way to create a new data model that has both entities, and can import as appropriate from the existing `storedata` files for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Core Data has versioning and migration capabilities you can use to move a data model forward when changes are made.  You can read the docs for this at this link: [Introduction to Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html)